# Remove tabs from data within double quotes

Tags: text-processing

I need to remove the extra tabs that are between data and before the end of line. below is a sample record.This record is a tab separated.The problem is when I am trying to load this data into database,the extra tabs that are there within the data causing the issue. To see the extra tabs,please copy below and paste into Notepad++ to understand the issue. is there any way to remove the tabs between "" "" enclosed data and tabs before the EOL.

```
"88115082436608 2018-12-07 02:32:08 4282    CTYGGJG BANK                    United States           FTFVGHVHGG|SRDRGFGFGHFG - CATATSSS-WC - TYTY - Relevant World-Check     2018-12-07 02:32:34 TYTUYUIIHHHIHUIH    GUGUUIUHUH BANK     UHJBJBHJGHUH    HGGGG   USA UUHHUIIKHJ BANK"    " JHHHNJMNJ|COMPANY BANK|COMPANY OF YUIUHIH 0.37495 Medium  0   1   Immaterial      User Adjudicated    ""additionally below are the mitigation factors. 1. The hits are more than uyhyhuh old"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
2. The entity has yuyyiy into. 3. It belongs to a well known                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
and bhjhjhhijji and has diverse ghjhjjhiujh in many locations    therefore   the well                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
"standing and uhyuhiuiui of the GHGHUGYG is considered.""   11492381    yiyuyy.jhh-ext@yuyihu.com   13904028    997380"
```

Comment: Can anyone help me to remove tabs atleast between ""    "".

Comment: The problem is that the `{} Code sample` function of this site converts tabs to spaces. Maybe you should upload your sample to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) or somewhere else.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the tabs? This looks like a perfectly well-formatted (well...) field from a CSV file, and the embedded quotes are even correctly escaped as `""`.  Are you trying to read the data as a tab-delimited file? Do you have access to a CSV parser such as `csvkit`, or a CSV parser library in whatever language you're using?

Comment: @Freddy I can't access pastebin from my office laptop..but what I need this to remove extra tabs that are within ""          "" data..but this data is divided into multiple lines..This is a bit urgent..if you can help it would be a great help..

Comment: I have to load this data into sql server and sql server is not reading this data properly

Comment: @Kusalananda..do you know how can we remove tabs between quotes?

Comment: just modify this https://superuser.com/questions/1131473/remove-quotes-between-string-in-notepad

Answer (score 0):

You can do it many ways, some of them being as shown below:

With the `sed` editor you can do it as follows (assuming the records have balanced double quotes) and I am showing `\t` for a `TAB` character, you might have to use a literal `TAB` inplace of that in case your `sed` is `POSIX`. And I am converting all `TABs` which are inside of double quotes to be changed to `%` character, YMMV. The outlying `TABs` aren't touched.

```
$ sed -e '
   /\n/!y/"/\n/
   /\n/{
      s//"/;s//"/
      :loop
         s/\(".*\)\t\(.*"\)/\1%\2/
      tloop
      /\n/!b
      H;s/.*//;x;D
   }
' input.file
```

Using `Perl` simplifies the matters quite a bit:

```
$ perl -lpe 's/(?<=")(.*?)(?=")/$1 =~ y[\t][%]r/eg' input.file
```

HTH

Comment: @rakesh..are you still here

Comment: Awesome Rakesh..it worked:)

Comment: Rakesh..One more thing can you also convert that multi line data into one line data that is enclosed in quotes

Comment: @user313150 can you give an example of a sample input after passing it thru the `cat -nvet` command.

Comment: @RakeshSharma Using CentOS 7 and neither of these commands worked for me (saw *all* tabs being replaced). Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: @lampShadesDrifter Can you list out the `sed` and `perl` versions used in your distro. type `sed --version` and `perl --version` for that.

Comment: @RakeshSharma Seeing `GNU sed v4.2.2` and `perl v5.16.3`

Comment: @lampShadesDrifter yes this is doing all `TAB -> %`. Is that not correct ?

Comment: @lampShadesDrifter Can you provide a realistic input on pastebin ?

Comment: @RakeshSharma yes this is doing all `TAB -> %`, from the post I expect it to remove *only* TAB characters that are *inside quotes*, but instead seems indiscriminate. Some test input posted here: https://pastebin.com/LPTsRPLM. And what I see when running the sed command: `"this string%has a tab"%1234%567%"this string has none"%"this one does"`.

Comment: `perl -lpe 's/(".*?")/$1 =~ y|\t|*|r/ge' yourfile` try this.